# how to select rows from excel sheet in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ado, ole

Hi I have written a code to read from excel sheets and query them according to filter set
But am stuck at

```
Select * from [sheetname] where [col] not like '%something%'
```

How can I write the not part?
Rest all query just work fine
The one above ignores the not and executes

Comment: have you tried the NOT operator '<>'?

Comment: `NOT LIKE` should work - what errors/bad results are you getting?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's tough to guess what could help...maybe storing your data in a datatable and using a rowfilter would help?

Comment: Please post some sample data, show the exact query you're using, and show what the output is, and explain why that output isn't what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use ADO and OLE to read your spreadsheet, I would recommend using [EP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It's a project that allows you to work with Spreadsheets in a much better OOP paradigm. It also abstracts all of the gotchas that come from the different internal formatting of .xlsx files versus the older .xls files.

Comment: It's like almost I am doing the same thing but only to filter I am not getting the query rest I can select rows on condition EQUAL TO or like just can't do is NOT LIKE

Comment: @aadilsiddiqui _Why_ can't you use `NOT LIKE`?  It's perfectly valid syntax.  Are you getting an error or bad results?

Comment: I get the same result as by using LIKE, it seems like it's ignoring the NOT part

Answer (score 0):

Is it just you don't have quotes around `%something%`?

Check out [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database/) if you want to melt your brain with Excel possibilities (search the comments for 'not like'), and perhaps solve your problem at the same time.

Comment: I do have quotes '%something%'